# How to access HDFS file ffom servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, servlets, hadoop

I tried to connect with Hdfs using Servlet in eclipse but I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration
```

If anyone know how to connect Hdfs in Servlet?

Comment: I think it's because you do not add the hadoop jars to your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: i add all the jar file and also set the deployment path.
and my jar file version is same as hadoop version

Comment: Have you add `commons-configuration-x.y.z.jar`? 
`org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration` is in this jar.

Comment: please know me... if you know how to access Hdfs using servlet. and any link which gives me idea how to access hdfs in servlet

Comment: The code is same between Servlet and Java application. Could you post your codes here? There may be some classpath or configuraion issue due to the different environment of Servlet and Java application.

Comment: protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
 out.println("hello world");
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
    try
    {
     out.println(conf.get("fs.default.name"));
     FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
     }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

Comment: Error is occur at FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);

Comment: As I mentioned, the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration` happens because you do not add `commons-configuration-x.y.z.jar` to WEB-INF/lib, can you check it? You codes is fine.

Comment: i import all jars, import below classes and also set deployment path.
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient;

Comment: this is an another error 
[javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosName]

Comment: Can you post all of your jars in the deployment path?

Comment: okay,,,i solved my problem thanks you zsxwing